# A display error occurs when v-ripple is applied to an element in VItem in the slot

Tags: vuetify.js

this is vuetify [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpdUctuwjAQ/JWROQRUJxHPthHQ9ht6JBxCsqAIB0eOQa2i/Hv9aAnpyfbu7HhmZ9eyRuXxR11HtyuxhK01VbXING3TC7C+haUphCclrzVuYSULEpuUuTNlDuNQRaazUGcHQUjsRGNA7ryDDOyPGiPbMogW9oLuAXT/EyMH0PJ0EsRRNp8kKNdU/INbXvX4hNGpyroWNKwmjf4WZHX1VG8IDll+tvYuRZhLIVUCRUWABEGQsiHDey7K/GwYvKhheyDJiiq2rfcXafrS6Lp1bGoD4bFWj8Zj77xfWDwIwyP6TfuEfod8RKY0GDLPJjfL0GhIuzZQVrVUGq3xeUSHo5IVAhN+YOFALi+NhgsYG4sZT/qyi9SUd1OOGcecY8Gx5FhxPHO8cLzuoyqrx4TNFuPWq7b2zTobWZG7B3gCcdvrJoZ7HXuJRhzrOJtHi2g2ZfayjFZs/wN8x8aj)

this is all my code:

```html
  <v-item-group v-model="model">
    <v-data-table :items="items">
      <template #item="{ item }">
        <v-item #="{ toggle, isSelected }">
          <tr
            v-ripple
            :style="isSelected ? 'background-color: red' : ''"
            @click="toggle"
          >
            <td>{{ item.text }}</td>
          </tr>
        </v-item>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-item-group>
```

```js
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const model = ref();
  const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].map(e => ({
    text: 'some text' + e,
  }))
```

I just want to apply ripple to each row of VDataTable,
but when I click the `tr` element, ripple will be shown like this: [image]

Is there any way to make ripple display properly？

I found that it would be correct if I didn't use `isSelected` in `style`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. When you click the tr, v-ripple inserts an element containing the animation. But the subsequent update to `style` causes the tr element to be replaced and the element from the v-ripple is moved to the parent, giving you the broken animation.

Instead of using `:style`, use `:class`, which does not have that problem. You can use Vuetify's `bg-red` class or provide your own:

```html
<tr
  v-ripple 
  :class="{'bg-red': isSelected}"
  @click="toggle"
>
```

Have a look at the updated [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpdkdtuwjAMhl/lV7goaGkrjtuqgrZn2CVwUVpTVWtJlAQ0qeq7L4eN01Uc+7P92972TKsy/ZQyuZyJZSw31Mm2MLTZnYD8EjfWEddKnCUucScqatc75t8d84ynqsIUsSkOLSFzGdpC/r1CFvsvjZELWaKHMzDcQdeeGHnAiLpuiaPRX9RSaah6wl1dZaWpRkrXvWwL7br30aGOFVVRdpdrU/FRtk35bYlQ+qmYK1dt+qAsMfRjMAx5an0PLVOj7iWnQfNt1PRhjYG47Sjs9i8pLNe6HpLsV5d2JgNNxoeBppNCGfRQdMSAoxIdInu2yOFAKU7awJ8Ga8eMJze3P4Z1b6ccM445x4JjybHieOV443jfJ10hx4T1BuM+qHbjZ4i06MjbEV5A3MWGia2dp0GiFccGzubJIplNmTOWyYrtfwFlVbg7)